# Using jQuery to transform footer when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am editing a site that has a sticky footer `#sticky-footer-wrap` this div has the CSS properties `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` so it hangs at the bottom of the page.

Once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the full size, expanded footer `#exp-footer` is displayed and `#sticky-footer-wrap` is hidden.

This is the JS I am currently using:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('#sticky-footer-wrap').hide();
        $('#exp-footer').show();
        var scrollY = $('body').scrollTop()?$('body').scrollTop():$('html').scrollTop();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollY + $('#exp-footer').outerHeight()
        }, 'medium');
    }
});
```

Now I am stuck on how to properly reverse this, ie when the user scrolls back up 365px (the height of `#exp-footer`), I want `#exp-footer` to `hide()` or `slideUp()` and `#sticky-footer-wrap` to be displayed once more.

I have tried a few different ways, all of which are buggy - so I think I've been going about this the wrong way. My question is, what would be the best way to achieve this?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqPVP/

Comment: Posting your code as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice..

Comment: refer this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/e9hyw/

Comment: I have just added a fiddle in my first post